# Circulation around airfoil implies infinite kinetic energy, but where from?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, lift

The standard model for the circulation around an airfoil is $W(z) = C \log(z)$, which implies that the velocity around an airfoil moving through a 2D fluid at rest goes $\sim 1/r$ with increasing distance $r$, the density of kinetic energy goes $\sim 1/r^2$ and hence the total kinetic energy $\int r\,dr \int d\varphi \, \ldots$ of a disk of radius $R$ diverges $\sim \log(R)$ to infinity.

The only reference to this I've found so far in the literature is a brief remark in [Batchelor's text book](https://books.google.de/books?id=aXQgAwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA404&dq=fluid%20with%20circulation%20infinite%20kinetic%20energy&hl=de&pg=PA404#v=onepage&q=fluid%20with%20circulation%20infinite%20kinetic%20energy&f=false).

It seems as though building up this energy requires additional work to be done during flight (even an infinite amount of energy, so possibly a constant finite amount of power for infinite time). This seems to be remotely related to induced drag; induced drag, however, also occurs when in the steady state with circulation extending to infinity.

Any ideas? References?

Comment: @D.Halsey I'm referring to Kutta-Joukowski outside of the boundary layer.

Comment: @D.Halsey The circulation along a (large enough) circle does not depend on its radius, so $\oint {\mathbf v}_{c} \cdot d{\mathbf s} \sim 1$, and hence $v_c ∼1/r$.

Answer (score 0):

In the frame in which the wing is stationary there is a uniform flow, so there  already infinite energy. The   velocity perturbation falls of as $1/r^2$, so the extra energy is finite.

In the frame where the aircraft is moving the induced vortex is a closed loop -- so a dipole. So  again the velocity perturbation falls off as $1/r^2$ far away from the aircraft.

Comment: Could you please explain how you arrive at the $1/r^2$ in the first paragraph? The circulation does not depend on the path around the airfoil, in particular it does not depend on the radius of a circular path, hence the difference in velocity is $\sim 1/r$.

In the second paragraph you are referring to the horseshoe vortex? As the starting vortex is created in finite time and its total energy remains bounded for all times, I don't see how it could compensate for the circulation caused by the airfoil.

Comment: You can find an explantion of the inverse square disturbance in ourlecture notes https://goldbart.gatech.edu/PostScript/MS_PG_book/bookmaster.pdf page after eq 17.79.  The horseshoe vortex includes the circulation around the wing and clearly has finite energy.  Note that energy is frame dependent.

Comment: Eq. (17.79) does not refer to a flow with non-zero circulation? – For sure, energy is frame-dependent; that's why I'd like to look at a moving wing in a fluid at rest, not only because that's what happening at the airport, but also because there is one infinity less to deal with.

Comment: The moving wing leaves two (oppositely  circulating),  wingtip vortices trailing behind. The energy per unit length of the two vorticles is finite because the total circulation  is zero. The (finite) energy per unit length times the forward velocity is the induced drag.

Comment: Agreed. But in my question I was talking of the steady state, so that the starting vortex is infinitely distant and the circulation (around the wing, not including the starting vortex) is asymptotically constant $\neq 0$ to infinity. On first sight, the (infinite) kinetic energy (relative to the air at rest) stored in this velocity field does not seem to come from induced drag (even though it's accumulated over an infinite duration of flight).